# Java ORM, Can a java bean be mapped to a view

Tags: java, orm

We have a very big table, we use it to store contract information about different business types.

depends the actual business type, different columns in that table will be used.

If we created views on that table with different business types, can these views be used in

any java ORM framework ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe yes. View is the DB level abstraction that allows user to run queries against it exactly as against regular table. ORM framework is just yet another user from DB perspective, so this approach should work.

But I personally do not think this is the best solution. I believe that DB should do what it knows to do: store normalized data in tables. Business layer (written in java in our case) should be responsible on all logic including filtering of data from the DB. This means that view you mentioned should be probably "implemented" in buseness layer. For example you can wrap your DAO with aspect that adds some additional conditions to WHERE clause, so you get effect of "view" implemented in java. This gives you a lot of advantages like flexibility etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use JPA and map your views as child classes of a common parent. This will allow you to map just the properties that are valid for each particular child class, while maintaining the common set of properties in the parent.

Heres a simple example:

```
@Entity
@Table("myTable")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class Common {
    // Common fields, including ID
}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("special1")
public class Specialized1 extends Common {
    // Specialized fields here
}
```

In the example above you have a common table with a 'type' column that is used to distinguish which fields are valid for the mapped ORM classes.

There are quite a few good tutorials on the Internet. [Here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Inheritance) is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

The ORM layer essentially just generates SQL, so I guess using a `VIEW` would work if all the SQL could be applied to a `VIEW` rather than a `TABLE`. Only `UPDATE`s and `INSERT`s could have a problem. If you can update through the view it should be OK; whether this is possible will depend on the `VIEW` and the RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveJDBC works with views as if they were normal tables. Check out at http://javalite.io.